# Render query algolia mapbox?

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, maps, mapbox, algolia

I am currently using algolia place and mapbox.
I would like when I type in the input that the results are displayed in the mbox map.
I use reactjs
Does anyone have an example for me?
Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, Algolia Places reaches End of Life on May 31st, 2022. You should consider using another Places library for your project.

https://community.algolia.com/places/documentation.html